# R - ignore error on warn in certain scenarios, get results

Tags: r, try-catch

I set options( warn = 2 ).  I require awareness of a warning when triggered and prefer to stop execution.  That said, in a few cases a warning is expected and the program should continue execution.  Using tryCatch() properly traps the error, however the resulting data is not available.

Here's a concrete example:

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y = c(1,1,1,0,0,0)
result = glm( y~x , family = binomial( link = "logit" ) )
```

Wrapping glm in tryCatch(), the result isn't populated.  That makes sense since glm's warning is converted into an error before it has the chance to return.  Is there a best practice in this scenario?  Is it simply to set options(warn=0) before the glm call and then restore after the call?  Or is there a better pattern?

I'm certain this is what I want to do.  There is no standard for warnings.  Sometimes a warning is trivial whereas other times its quite serious.  That's why I convert warnings to errors as default.  Still, I need the ability to ignore warnings in certain situations where I'm absolutely certain that I can ignore the warning.  In those cases, I want the result!

**Edit**
Here's the try-catch:

```
tryCatch(  { result = glm( y~x , family = binomial( link = "logit" ) ) } , error = function(e) { print("test") } )
```

Comment: Could you provide the `tryCatch` block you tried?

Comment: @Joshua - added as edit to original post.  Am I using tryCatch improperly?

Comment: I'm not sure; I thought it may help others help you.  FWIW, I think `suppressWarnings` is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `suppressWarnings()`

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/warning.html

```
 x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
 y = c(1,1,1,0,0,0)
 result = suppressWarnings(glm( y~x , family = binomial( link = "logit" ) ))
 result

 Call:  glm(formula = y ~ x, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

 Coefficients:
 (Intercept)            x  
      165.32       -47.23  

 Degrees of Freedom: 5 Total (i.e. Null);  4 Residual
 Null Deviance:      8.318 
 Residual Deviance: 2.215e-10    AIC: 4
```

Edit 1 ==================================

If you want to show the error from the above `glm()` statement somewhere later in your code, you can add the `warnings()` statement.

```
 stoerr <- warnings()   
 stoerr

 Warning message:
 glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

Comment: @SFun28: If you still want to show the error, add warnings() where ever you want the error to show up.

Comment: didn't quite follow your last comment.  suppressWarnings will only suppress the contained code, right?

Comment: @SFun28: Correct, but just in case you wanted to show that error message later, you can.  See the edit that I added to my post above.

Comment: Are you sure this is working? `suppressWarnings(warning("testit"));warnings()` gives `NULL`.